# High PWM frequency weird shape

Tags: pwm, signal, measurement, stm32f4

Using a STM32F407 if I generate a 200 Hz signal it looks like this:

[image]

If I want a higher frequency, for instance 10 kHz I get this:
[image]

I am using a PicoScope 2205A, resolution 8 bits at 200Ms/s, bandwith 25MHz.

Does anyone know what is happening ?

P.S I configured the pin as very high speed in the OSPEED register.

Comment: Looks like your scope is unable to sample this frequency properly. Or the settings you are using it with are not appropriate for this frequency.

Comment: What is the time scale on your scope in the second image. Is it adjustable? You may just be seeing tons of aliasing (the signal might actually be switching much faster, you are just massively undersampling it).

Comment: From some internet articles I see that the picoscope software has a setting/display of the sampling rate for the given signal. What is it in your case? Or even better, post the screen of the full window where we can see all of the data.

Comment: Yeah, I found the mistake. It had a sample of 6kS in the settings for the channel. Also the time scale was 3ms/div. I changed the sampling rate and now works fine.... Sorry for bothering you, guys.

Comment: Have seen this kind of problem from picoscope users especially. @EugeneSh. & Justin recognize a suspect display problem that may be caused by a small section of a long record being viewed. Recognizing a digital sampling problem is an additional skill that  newer 'scope users must overcome. Another is the "wagon-wheel-sampling" timebase problem.

Comment: @pantarhei - Hi, Please can you write *and accept* an answer, since you have solved this problem :-) That way, this question is removed from the "unanswered list" and we don't get future nags to answer it. Also, as highlighted by *glen_geek*, some people haven't seen this type of problem before, and can learn from a clear explanation. Even better if you can include "good" and "bad" scope images, and show the relevant changes of settings for each one. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to modify the sampling rate of the channel. Even if the info window shows you 25Ms/s or something like this you have modify it from the channel settings because it has other value. Also adjust the scale time until the signal is clear. It worked for me.